# Jquery autocomplete to search within more than one columns of a table

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

[Jquery UI's autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)  has given the solution to searching through one column of a table. So if you get the source from a table with firstname field then you can only search with firstname.

But say you have more than one fields to search against like firstname, lastname, postcode, contactNumber. Then in that case how would you implement something like this for autosuggest.

I mean that user should be able to search with whatever field they like and the autosuggest should be able to give them the suggestions based on that.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source can be an array, a string or a function.

You'd have to write a custom function to read all the values in all the columns of the tables and store them in an array.  Then call the `.source` method with your array.

For bonus points, a series of checkboxes above the search field would ask the user to search only those columns.

```
[ ] FirstName   [X] Lastname   [X] Department
_Smith_____
John   Smith    IT
Waylon Smithers Assistant to the Assistant Regional Manager
Jackie Brown    Gunsmith
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Your point made me think and I am now going to get the resultset in one columns as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359121/sql-query-to-get-the-resultset-in-two-columns-only