# SQL query to get the resultset in two columns only

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, unpivot

I have this table:

```
id  fName  lName   Address    PostCode  ContactNumber
-----------------------------------------------------
1  Tom     Daley   London     EC1 4EQ   075825485665
2  Jessica Ennis   Sheffield  SF2 3ER   075668956665
3  Joe     Bloggs  Glasgow    G3 2AZ    075659565666
```

I want a query to give me the results like this:

```
id | label
1  | Tom
1  | Daley
1  | London
1  | EC1 4EQ
1  | 075825485665
2  | Jessica
2  | Ennis
2  | Sheffied
```

and so on so forth.

Any suggestions please on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to turn the columns into rows:

```
select id, value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in ([fName], [lName], [Address], [PostCode], [ContactNumber])
) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa9e0/1).

The *unpivot* will require the datatype on all of the columns to be the same. So you might have to perform a `cast`/`convert` on any columns with different datatypes similar to this:

```
select id, value
from
(
  select id, [fName], [lName], [Address], [PostCode],
    cast([ContactNumber] as varchar(15)) [ContactNumber]
  from yourtable
) src
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in ([fName], [lName], [Address], [PostCode], [ContactNumber])
) unpiv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d597a/1).

Starting in SQL Server 2008, this can also be written using a `CROSS APPLY` with a `VALUES`:

```
select t.id,
  c.value
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  values(fName), 
    (lName), 
    (Address), 
    (PostCode), 
    (cast(ContactNumber as varchar(15)))
) c (value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d597a/5)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT
 id, fName as label
FROM
 table

UNION ALL

SELECT
 id, lName
FROM
 table

UNION ALL

SELECT
 id, Address
FROM
 table

...etc
```